# What do we say to a patient?

Tags: word-choice

When somebody is patient/sick (what is the difference?) when we see him and we want to make him feel better?

For example :

- I hope you getting better soon.
- I hope see you good soon..

Which one?

Any better words in such this cases?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! If you had any questions about the workings of the site, visit [the help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) or take a [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "patient" is a person (or animal) who is being treated for a medical (or veterinary) problem.  This meaning of "patient" is a noun.  There is another meaning of "patient" that is an adjective.

A person (or animal) who is "sick" has a medical (or veterinary) problem that is not merely a simple physical condition.  For example, a sickness can include the effects of a disease.  Simply having a broken bone (unless there is an infection) is not a "sickness".  "Sick" is an adjective.

Neither of your examples is grammatically correct.  The following options sound natural to my (American) ear:

- I hope you get better soon.
- I hope you get well soon.
- I hope to see you soon.

As [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113) points out, "Get well soon" is an idiom.  Google Images has lots of pictures of "[Get well soon](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=get+well+soon&tbm=isch)" greeting cards.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "Get well soon" is a standard stock phrase that's often found on greeting cards. One can type in "get well soon" or "get well soon card" into [Google images](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+well+soon+card%22&rls=en&tbm=isch&oq=) and find dozens of examples.

Comment: Hey, I think you should undelete your "home / house" answer :) It just needs a little tweak (to include plurals) and then it will be very sound, easy to understand, practical advice. Very useful indeed for learners ... :)

Answer (score 1):

1. *Patient* (in the sense of suffering from a disease) is used only as a noun, not an adjective, so you should say *When somebody is **sick*** or *When somebody is **a** patient*. *Sick* is to my mind better; *patient* tends to refer to the relationship between sick people and their caregivers.
2. *Hope* takes two sorts of complement clause:

   - a clause with a **finite** (tensed) verb, optionally introduced by *that*:

     > I hope (that) you will be getting better soon.  *OR*
     >   I hope (that) you get better soon.
   - a clause with a **marked** infinitive (the 'marker' is **to**), whose subject is the same as the person hoping:

     > I hope to see you well soon.

Answer (score 1):

We will say

> I hope you get better soon.

Answer (score 0):

'I/we hope you get better soon.'

Or we can simply say:

'Get better soon' or 'You'll be better soon'.

You can also add:

'You're in my/our thoughts (and prayers)'.

Note that as a noun, *a patient* is someone seeking medical assistance. The plural form is *patients*.

This plural form sounds the same as the noun *patience*, which means *tolerance toward delay or incompetence*.

That the two words sound the same allows many jokes or plays on word involving the two words, such as

That doctor would have more *patients* if he had more *patience*.

In addition, the adjectival form of *patience* is *patient* which allows the following:

A *patient patient* is a patient (someone seeking medical help) who is patient (showing tolerance toward delay or incompetence).

Answer (score 0):

Nurses say: How are we today? (with a brilliant smile, when one is slightly recovering from near-death)